# How to create listener on server side which should give some response?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-boot

Hi i am building project with spring boot and using socket programming to communicate between client and server . I have started my project on localhost with port number 8080.
And i run my client programme using this code:

```
String serverName = "localhost";
        int port = 8080;
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port "
                    + port);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                    + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
            System.out.println("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
            out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
            InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This programme prints message "Just connected to 127.0.0.1:8080" but throws exception at line above "client.close":

```
Connecting to localhost on port 8080
Just connected to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
Hello from /127.0.0.1:37281
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at com.oodles.Demo.App.main(App.java:39)
```

My Requirement is How to create listener on server side which can process the message from client and sends back some response

Answer (score 0):

I check your code.Connection ok but the client doesn't response from server when you have used in.readUTF();

You can use the bellow code:

String serverName = "localhost";
        int port = 8080;

```
    try {
        System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port "
                + port);
        Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
        System.out.println("Just connected to "
                + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
        System.out.println("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
        out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
        InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

        if (in.read() != -1) {
            System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
        }

        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since spring boot runs on tomcat which is understands HTTP only. So here your client is connecting to the tomcat server, which can understands HTTP only. So if you want to connect to spring-boot app over HTTP, then send HTTP request over your TCP connection to the spring-boot app. Otherwise implement a component on spring-boot application which can accept TCP connection on some other port and handle as per your protocol.